# getTextContent() through "Null pointers should not be dereferenced"

Tags: java, java-11

I have a below method where we are using "getTextContent()"  to get text content of the current node.

```
if (getElement(Details, null, "AMB") != null) {
            payload.put("<String>",
                    getElement(Details, null, "AMB").getTextContent().trim());
        }
```

I am always getting sonarqube error "Null pointers should not be dereferenced" Get emement method are below

```
private Element getElement(Node node, String errMessage, String... paths) {
        NodeList nodeList;
        Element element = (Element) node;
        for (String path : paths) {
            nodeList = element.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", path);
            if (checkList(nodeList)) {
                element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
            } else {
                if (errMessage != null) {
                    log.error("Unable to read node element {}", errMessage);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        return element;
    }
```

I am not sure How I can handle this condition. I tried to put another "if" inside if condition. But again sonar qube through more error

Could you please help some one it is blocker to me.

Comment: As `getElement` can return `null`, doing `getElement(Details, null, "AMB").getTextContent()` is dangerous. You need to check whether the value returned by `getElement` is nulll before you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I am checking this confition "if (getElement(Details, null, "AMB") != null)"

Comment: Assign the result to a local variable and then check it, and use the local variable if it isn't null.

Comment: I Did this                                                                                                                   
            Element receiverstr = getElement(receiverAccDetails, null, "Id");
    receiverBban = receiverstr.getTextContent().trim();
    payload.put(RECEIVER_TRANSACTION_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, receiverBban);   but getting same result

Comment: Please update your question with your current code, and *exactly* what sonarqube is saying.

Comment: It might be that `getTextContent` is returning null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose, the fact that you have a conditional like `getElement(Details, null, "AMB") != null` hints to the code audit tool that the method `getElement` may return `null`. In that case, the actual implementation code of the invoked method is not relevant.

Therefore, the tool produces a warning because the subsequent `getElement(Details, null, "AMB").getTextContent().trim()` dereferences the result of a call to `getElement` without a `null` check.

You seem to assume that two subsequent invocations of `getElement(Details, null, "AMB")` will return the same result, hence, the preceding test is sufficient, but code audit tools normally do not make such an assumption.

The simplest way to fix this, is to use a local variable to hold the result, which is generally to prefer over repeating expressions.

```java
Element e = getElement(Details, null, "AMB");
if(e != null) {
    payload.put("<String>", e.getTextContent().trim());
}
```

This should be sufficient to convince any code checking tool that the condition and the subsequent use refer to the same value, hence, `e` can not be `null` at the `e.getTextContent()` invocation.

Comment: Thanks this solution is working